# Trying to manually commit during interceptor managed transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, interceptor

This is a weird situation and I normally would never do it but our system has unfortunately now required this kind of scenario.

**The System**
We are running a Spring/Hibernate applications that is using OpenSessionInView and TransactionInterceptor to manage our transactions. For the most part it works great. However, we have recently required the need to spawn a number of threads to make some concurrent HTTP requests to providers.

**The Problem**
We need the entity that is passed into the thread to have all of the data that we have updated in our current transaction. The problem is we spawn the thread deep down in the guts of our service layer and it's very difficult to make a smaller transaction to allow this work. We tried originally just passing the entity to the thread and just calling:

```
leadDao.update(lead);
```

The problem is that we than get the error about the entity living in two sessions. Next we try to commit the original transaction and reopen as soon as the threads are complete.
This is what I have listed here.

```
try {
        logger.info("------- BEGIN MULTITHREAD PING for leadId:" + lead.getId());
        start = new Date();
        leadDao.commitTransaction();
        List<Future<T>> futures = pool.invokeAll(buyerClientThreads, lead.getAffiliate().getPingTimeout(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++) {
            Future<T> future = futures.get(i);
            T leadStatus = null;
            try {
                leadStatus = future.get();
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.debug("Retrieved results from thread buyer" + leadStatus.getLeadBuyer().getName() + " leadId:" + leadStatus.getLead().getId() + " time:" + DateUtils.formatDate(start, "HH:mm:ss"));
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                leadStatus = extractErrorPingLeadStatus(lead, "Timeout - CancellationException", buyerClientThreads.get(i).getBuyerClient().getLeadBuyer(), buyerClientThreads.get(i).getBuyerClient().constructPingLeadStatusInstance());
                leadStatus.setTimeout(true);
                leadStatus.setResponseTime(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime());
                logger.debug("We had a ping that didn't make it in time");
            }
            if (leadStatus != null) {
                completed.add(leadStatus);
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.debug("There was a problem calling the pool of pings", e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        logger.error("There was a problem calling the pool of pings", e);
    }
    leadDao.beginNewTransaction();
```

The begin transaction looks like this:

```
public void beginNewTransaction() {
    if (getCurrentSession().isConnected()) {
        logger.info("Session is not connected");
        getCurrentSession().reconnect();
        if (getCurrentSession().isConnected()) {
            logger.info("Now connected!");
        } else {
            logger.info("STill not connected---------------");
        }
    } else if (getCurrentSession().isOpen()) {
        logger.info("Session is not open");
    }
    getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    logger.info("BEGINNING TRANSAACTION - " + getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive());

}
```

The threads are using TransactionTemplates since my buyerClient object is not managed by spring (long involved requirements).
Here is that code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T processPing(Lead lead) {
        Date now = new Date();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("BEGIN PINGING BUYER " + getLeadBuyer().getName() + " for leadId:" + lead.getId() + " time:" + DateUtils.formatDate(now, "HH:mm:ss:Z"));
        }
        Object leadStatus = transaction(lead);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("PING COMPLETE FOR BUYER " + getLeadBuyer().getName() + " for leadId:" + lead.getId() + " time:" + DateUtils.formatDate(now, "HH:mm:ss:Z"));
        }
        return (T) leadStatus;
    }

    public T transaction(final Lead incomingLead) {
        final T pingLeadStatus = this.constructPingLeadStatusInstance();
        Lead lead = leadDao.fetchLeadById(incomingLead.getId());    
        T object = transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<T>() {

            @Override
            public T doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                Date startTime = null, endTime = null;

                logger.info("incomingLead obfid:" + incomingLead.getObfuscatedAffiliateId() + " affiliateId:" + incomingLead.getAffiliate().getId());

                T leadStatus = null;
                if (leadStatus == null) {
                    leadStatus = filterLead(incomingLead);
                }
                if (leadStatus == null) {
                    leadStatus = pingLeadStatus;
                    leadStatus.setLead(incomingLead);
...LOTS OF CODE
}
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
                    logger.debug("RETURNING LEADSTATUS FOR BUYER " + getLeadBuyer().getName() + " for leadId:" + incomingLead.getId() + " time:" + DateUtils.formatDate(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss:Z"));
                return leadStatus;
            }
        });
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Transaction complete for buyer:" + getLeadBuyer().getName() + " leadId:" + incomingLead.getId() + " time:" + DateUtils.formatDate(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss:Z"));
        }

        return object;
    }
```

However, when we begin our new transaction we get this error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:660)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
```

**My Goal**
My goal is to be able to have that entity fully initalized on the other side or Does anyone have any ideas on how I can commit the data to the database so the thread can have a fully populated object. Or, have a way to query for a full object?
Thanks I know this is really involved. I apologize if I haven't been clear enough.

**I have tried**
Hibernate.initialize()
saveWithFlush()
update(lead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @gkamal for your help.
For everyone living in posterity. The answer to my dilemma was a left over call to hibernateTemplate instead of getCurrentSession(). I made the move about a year and a half ago and for some reason missed a few key places. This was generating a second transaction. After that I was able to use @gkamal suggestion and evict the object and grab it again.

This post helped me figure it out:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?26782-Illegal-attempt-to-associate-a-collection-with-two-open-sessions

Answer (score 0):

I didn't follow everything - you can try one of this to workaround the issue that you get about the same object being associated with two sessions.

```
// do this in the main thread to detach the object 
// from the current session 
// if it has associations that also need to be handled the cascade=evict should
// be specified. Other option is to do flush & clear on the session.
session.evict(object);


// pass the object to the other thread

// in the other thread - use merge
session.merge(object)
```

Second approach - create a deep copy of the object and pass the copy.  This can be easily achieved if your entity classes are serializable - just serialize the object and deserialize.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. When I tried the evict I got this error:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
 at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:435)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:66)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:122)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:83)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(

Comment: Or This depending on if I use update (the error above) or merge:
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.qe.model.lead.LifeLead#9943840]
 at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:638)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOr

Comment: I think the new error is because of the object is referring to other entities.  You need to evict those as well or set the cascade attribute on the association to include evict.  Other option as I mentioned in my answer is to do a flush & clear - so all the objects are detached from the first session and then do a merge in the second session.

Comment: I got this now: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.qe.model.lead.HealthLead#9956568] 
Doh! I see a bug. Let me try this again.

Comment: Still getting org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.qe.model.lead.AutoLead#9957286] 
I am running:
getCurrentSession().save(lead);
evict(lead);
getCurrentSession().flush();
getCurrentSession().clear();
And in my thread I am calling:  Lead incomingLead = leadDao.merge(lead);

Comment: Can you try a flush and clear of the second session as well. I think the associated object (AutoLead) have already been loaded in the second session.  This is getting uglier :-(

Comment: Still getting it:org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.qe.model.lead.AutoLead#9968386]
I get it when I call flush of all things: getCurrentSession().flush(); Before I even get to my threads!